# XOR of two short integers

Tags: java, xor

I am calculating `XOR` of two `short integers` using `XOR ^` operator in a traditional fashion. Below is the method-

```
short a=197;
short b=341;
short y = (short) (a ^ b);
```

However the XOR always returned integer but in my case inputs are short integer, that is why i am casting short to the XOR output. The XOR can be calculated in different manners (example: using `BigInteger` etc.) but performance wise (less time) which is the best for short integers? While keeping performance in mind, should i first convert each short integer to binary number using `Integer.toBinaryString(number)` then apply bitwise XOR?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
short s1 = ...
short s2 = ...
short result = (short) (s1 ^ s2);
```

This is the most efficient way to XOR two `short`s together. It does not run into the overhead of creating `BigInteger`s and the cast will never cause an overflow issue as both `s1` and `s2` are `short`s to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

It's not really clear what you mean by "convert each short integer to binary number" - a short is already a number, and its representation is naturally binary anyway.

You just want:

```
short x = ...;
short y = ...;
short z = (short) (x ^ y);
```

You need the cast as `x ^ y` will promote both to `int`, and the result will be an `int`. However, the result will have to be in the range of a `short` anyway, so it's safe to perform this cast without losing information.

See [section 15.22.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1) for more information about XOR in particular and [section 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) for information on binary numeric promotion in general.

Comment: @EricJ.: Were you still looking at the version where I didn't have parentheses round the `(x ^ y)`? I fixed that a while ago :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: By ""convert each short integer to binary number"" i meant that should i first convert each short integer to binary string using `Integer.toBinaryString(number)` then apply `bitwise XOR`?

Comment: @RaviJoshi: Why would you want to do that? Why convert it to a string when it's already in binary in memory? *Bitwise* XOR implies working on bits, not characters, surely...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ya, i got it now. thank you. `short c = (short) (a ^ b);` :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but hopefully this helps:

Java coerces both operands to type int.  That is why the result is an int.

so your shorts will be automatically converted to an int, and the XOR operation will be done very efficiently on the integer operands.

If one of the operands is a long, both types are instead coerced to a long.  However, that does not apply in your case.

Bottom line, given that both of your inputs are short, if you need a short result, the most efficient thing to do is

```
short result = (short) (operandA ^ operandB);
```